# Need help installing LiquidHaskell on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, haskell, liquid-haskell

for my bachelor thesis I want to write about and do a few experiments with LiquidHaskell.
I already installed Haskell/GHC and CVC4 as SMT Solver.
Now I am trying to install the liquid-package on my Ubuntu-Laptop but run into problems:

If I try the command `cabal install liquid-platform` I get the following output:

```
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring liquid-platform-0.8.10.2...
Building liquid-platform-0.8.10.2...
Failed to install liquid-platform-0.8.10.2
Build log ( /home/alex/.cabal/logs/liquid-platform-0.8.10.2.log ):
cabal: Entering directory '/tmp/cabal-tmp-2235/liquid-platform-0.8.10.2'
Configuring liquid-platform-0.8.10.2...
cabal: No libraries, executables, tests, or benchmarks are enabled for package
liquid-platform-0.8.10.2.
cabal: Leaving directory '/tmp/cabal-tmp-2235/liquid-platform-0.8.10.2'
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
liquid-platform-0.8.10.2 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

If I go the git route with

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/ucsd-progsys/liquidhaskell.git
cd liquidhaskell
stack install liquid-platform
```

I get this error:

```
Downloading lts-16.8 build plan ...RedownloadFailed Request {
  host                 = "raw.githubusercontent.com"
  port                 = 443
  secure               = True
  requestHeaders       = []
  path                 = "/fpco/lts-haskell/master//lts-16.8.yaml"
  queryString          = ""
  method               = "GET"
  proxy                = Nothing
  rawBody              = False
  redirectCount        = 10
  responseTimeout      = ResponseTimeoutDefault
  requestVersion       = HTTP/1.1
}
 "/home/alex/.stack/build-plan/lts-16.8.yaml" (Response {responseStatus = Status {statusCode = 404, 
statusMessage = "Not Found"}, responseVersion = HTTP/1.1, responseHeaders = [("Connection","keep-alive"),
("Content-Length","14"),("Content-Security-Policy","default-src 'none'; style-src 'unsafe-inline'; 
sandbox"),("Strict-Transport-Security","max-age=31536000"),("X-Content-Type-Options","nosniff"),("X-
Frame-Options","deny"),("X-XSS-Protection","1; mode=block"),("Content-Type","text/plain; charset=utf-8"),
("X-GitHub-Request-Id","5504:E1A3:27782:28EF3:605CC681"),("Accept-Ranges","bytes"),("Date","Thu, 25 Mar 
2021 17:21:05 GMT"),("Via","1.1 varnish"),("X-Served-By","cache-hhn4072-HHN"),("X-Cache","MISS"),("X-
Cache-Hits","0"),("X-Timer","S1616692865.098004,VS0,VE140"),("Vary","Authorization,Accept-Encoding"),
("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*"),("X-Fastly-Request-ID","60a420e0a48fc7ec7d566c9841aba6591995f43d"),
("Expires","Thu, 25 Mar 2021 17:26:05 GMT"),("Source-Age","0")], responseBody = (), responseCookieJar = 
CJ {expose = []}, responseClose' = ResponseClose})
```

I would greatly appreciate all help you could offer me.

Thanks in advance, Noodlez

Comment: Have you tried `cd`ing into your git clone and running plain `stack install`?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Ari. Yes I tried that, that's the second "route" and the accompanying output/error is the lower part of my original post

Comment: Have you tried `stack install` without `liquid-platform`?

Comment: Ah, now I understand what you meant. Unfortunately it produces the same RedownloadFailed Request error as with the liquid-platform input (see original post).